# Mapping UML Association class to Java Model code

Tags: orm, model, many-to-many, uml, model-associations

I would like to know the proper way to implement UML association class in Java programming code. I have Student and Course classes. Student can attend one or more Courses, Courses can be attended by one or more Student (many-to-many relationship). If I don't have any attribute in association class (despite course and student ids), would it be okey to implement it this way: `public class Course{ private List<Student> students  ...}` `public class Student{ private List<Course> course}`. Please explain me both situations, because I don't get it if I should have model `public CourseEnrollment { private Student; private Course; private LocalDate enrollementDate}` and lists of CourseEnrollments in Student and Course classes. [image]

What I tried is explained above with CourseEnrollment class and my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to implement an association class is to use a `Collection<CourseEnrollment>` e.g. an `ArrayList<CourseEnrollment>`, in both `Course` and `Student`, and make sure that CourseEnrollment has a property back to the respective `Course` and `Student`.

The navigation would then be indirect: Student -> List of enrolments -> corresponding courses, or Course -> List of enrolments -> corresponding students. The challenge in your code will be to maintain consistency, e.g. if your remove a student from a course,  you'll need not only to delete the enrollment from the course's collection, but also from the student's collection.

Another alternative is to use an independent [repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) of `CourseEnrollments`, that keeps a list of all the enrolments and provides efficient access for a student and a course, through two `HashMap`. The advantage is that there's only one place to manage the enrollment,  and students or courses can get the relevant and up-to-date links from there. Again, navigation is indirect, this time by querying the repository. The challenge here is to manage decoupling,  since every `Student` or `Course` would need to know about the repository.

You may have noticed, that in both cases, the trick is to implement the association class as a class,  and to decompose the direct association between `Student` and `Course` into an indirect association via the association class.

*P.S: In the UML semantics, the association class is at the same time a class and an association.  But it can have only one name.  Chose either `chooses` or `CourseEnrollment`,  but you should not use different names.*